# How to check if this $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lvert(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{1-\cos(\frac{1}{n})}\rvert$ series converges absolutely?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The series is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lvert(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{1-\cos(\frac{1}{n})}\rvert$ and I need to check if it converges absolutely. I know that it equals to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{1-\cos(\frac{1}{n})}$ but now I don't know what to do...

Comment: $\sqrt{1-\cos(1/n)}=\sqrt2\sin(1/2n)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $1-\cos(\frac{1}{n})=2\sin^2{\frac{1}{2n}}$.  Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{1-\cos(\frac{1}{n})}=\sqrt{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin{\frac{1}{2n}}$ and use limit comparison test.